# How can I make an image max-width respect a percentage parent div width?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have two floated left divs.. 
One with width = 20%
Another with width = 80%

Inside this 20% width div I have an image with 300px width...

If my 20% area is smaller then 300px, I would like to make my image resize and fits inside this 20% div...

Something like this:

```
<div class="container">

   <div style="float:left; width:20%;">

       <img src="imageWith300pxWidth.jpg" />

   </div>

   <div style="float:left; width:80%;"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.image {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

- If your container width is larger than 300px, your image will stick to 300px;
- If your container width is smaller then the image will resize to fit into it

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot. I'll set your answer as the best one as soon as possible (10 minutes). Thanks again.